# $G=\langle g_1,\ldots,g_n \rangle$. Proof that $x \in G \Rightarrow \exists k \in \mathbb{N}: x=x_1 \cdots x_k$ where $x_i \in \{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a *finite* group. Assume that $G=\langle g_1, \ldots, g_n \rangle$.

Show that each element in $G$ can be written as $x_1 \cdots x_k$ for a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x_1, \ldots, x_k \in \{g_1, \ldots, g_n\}$

**My attempt:**

Let $g \in G$. Since $G=\langle g_1, \ldots, g_n \rangle=\overline{\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}}$ we can write $g=x_1^{\epsilon_1} \cdots x_k^{\epsilon_k}$ where $x_i \in \{g_1, \ldots, g_n\}$ and $\epsilon_i= \pm 1$. Now I need to show that $\epsilon_i=1$ for all $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$, however I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Hint: in a finite group every element has finite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is finite, then so are the orders of all its elements, i.e. for each $g\in G$ there is an ord$(g)<\infty$ with $g^{\text{ord}(g)}=e$, the identity element. So if you need $g^{-1}$, you just need to use $$g^{-1}=g^{\text{ord}(g)-1}=\underbrace{gg\cdots g}_{\text{ord}(g)-1\text{ times}}.$$